# How to solve Allow access origion problem

Tags: reactjs, express

i have tried to upload mern project on cpanel but always get cors problem
I have use this function in express js but same problem occurred

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin , X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept , Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
});
```

Also tried to use cors package but same error
Express work on poet 5001 and react on port 4000
Any solution can try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all , it was cpanel cors problem and another one i need to add is bcrypt package cause an error so i used bcryptjs library

Answer (score 0):

try npm package [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
and use it as a middleware in server file .

```
app.use(cors())
```

this means allow all - *

Comment: thanks , but i have tried this method and the same issue still

Comment: Are you sure you problem exactly related with cors enabling in api ? Try to google CPanel cors problems too.

Comment: i have try this and modfied .htaccess file but still same problem